Snyk container monitor target name is not showing an IMAGE_TAG
Wanted to ask a question about Snyk cli container monitor of docker image. So we got a docker image for example reponame/image_name:image_tag. We are monitoring this image from cli like snyk container monitor reponame/image_name:image_tag. It monitors, but in snyk UI in projects page - in target it shows only reponame/image_name, without image_tag. However yes, when we open that project, like more detailed info shows that there is a tag, but in projects simply it wont work. Tried every options from docs, here's what we get the best ( putting a png right now, you'll see what we need) My question is, is there any possible way to achieve it? Thank you
Tried diffrent options from documentation.
Expecting a tag near the name

I think that you need to use the --project-name flag when running the snyk container monitor command. This flag allows you to give the project a unique name, which can include the image tag. Here's an example of how you can do it:
bash
snyk container monitor reponame/image_name:image_tag --project-name="image_name:image_tag"

This should get you sorted.
Feel free to reach out to Snyk experts on the DevSecCon discord for more help

Tried this one as well, dont know why photo is not loading, i hope I will be able to explain it, when i use just the same type you did, it simply creates the same, I see like only the reponame/image_name, without image_tag. But with --project-name it also creates lets say a project? Like one more step under the main name and there it show my image_tag.
Something really like this ---> reponame/image_name -->reponame/image_name:image_tag
But what I need, if its possible tho, only reponame/image_name:image_tag, no sections under it((
